# Running `gcloud beta code dev` using private python packages from Artifact Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a single private python package using Google Artifact Registry.

Within the requirements.txt, the index url is specified using

```
--extra-index-url ...
some_package==1.0.0
```

After running `gcloud auth application-default login`, this works when just simply running `pip install -r requirements.txt` from my virtualenv. However, this does not seem to work when I run `gcloud beta code dev` and it tries to build the Docker image. Maybe my assumption is wrong, but I figured it would have access to the credentials by simply providing the `application-default-credential` flag.

Dockerfile (keyring.txt installs keyring and google keyring)

```
# Use an official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Removes output stream buffering, allowing for more efficient logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Disable pip caching, smaller image as a result
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR 1
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements ./requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements/keyring.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements/production.txt

# Copy local code to the container image
COPY . .

CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT config.wsgi:application
```

Output

```
...
#9 5.475 WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 1 of 3. Reason: timed out
#9 5.531 WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 2 of 3. Reason: [Errno 113] No route to host
#9 8.539 User for us-central1-python.pkg.dev: WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 3 of 3. Reason: timed out
#9 8.542 WARNING: Authentication failed using Compute Engine authentication due to unavailable metadata server.
#9 8.542 WARNING: Failed to retrieve Application Default Credentials: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.
#9 8.542 WARNING: Trying to retrieve credentials from gcloud...
#9 8.542 WARNING: Failed to retrieve credentials from gcloud: gcloud command exited with status: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcloud'
#9 8.542 WARNING: Artifact Registry PyPI Keyring: No credentials could be found.
#9 8.542 WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to find credentials, Please run: `gcloud auth application-default login or export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path/to/service/account/key>`
...
```

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what the `application-default-credential` flag does? Is there any way to make this work locally?

I was expecting the docker image build to use the application default credential, but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The '**gcloud auth application-default login**' command stores the credentials in a file **'Adc.json'** that is located in the **'config/gcloud'** directory in the user's Home directory.

In the Docker Image build process, the above-mentioned directory doesn't exists that's why can't retrieve the credentials from the file. The **'gcloud'** command is also not installed which is why saying error **"'No such file or directory:'gcloud'**".

Mount the **'config/gcloud'** into Docker Container by using -v option by running the **'docker run'** command.

Comment: Mounting a volume is only for running, correct? I only need access to the credentials during the image build process, not running it.

Comment: @ZachPerkitny for credentials you can set the environment variable 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' in the Dockerfile path of a service account key file. It will allow Google Cloud Client libraries to use the specified service account key file for authentication instead of the application default credentials.

Comment: @ZachPerkitny mounting a volume can use for both running and building a container image.